# what is the best place to reload data in UITableView or UICollectionView in ios

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, afnetworking, viewdidload, reloaddata

I'm using AFNetworking to load data.In my case, I load data into a collectionview.
I load data inside my custom method and inside that I reload collectionview data.
And I call this method in viewDidLoad method. Why I'm asking this is, it takes more time to load data. I thought this is because of the place I reload collectionview data.I want to know ,can I speed up the process by reloading collectionview data in another method like viewwillappear or any other.hope your help.thank you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self loadcategoryData];

    SWRevealViewController *revealcontroller = self.revealViewController;
    if (revealcontroller) {
        [self.sideBarbutton setTarget:self.revealViewController];
        [self.sideBarbutton setAction:@selector(revealToggle:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)loadcategoryData
{
    post = nil;
    NSString *mainurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some url"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager GET:mainurl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        posts = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        post = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(NSDictionary *all in posts)
        {
            Categories *category = [Categories new];
            category.title = [all objectForKey:@"catname"];
            category.firsturl = [all objectForKey:@"url"];

            [self.maincollectionView reloadData];
            //call for images

            imagespost = nil;
            NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", category.firsturl];
            AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *managerone = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
            [managerone GET:imageUrl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {



                imagesposts = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
                NSArray *resultone = [imagesposts objectForKey:@"posts"];
                imagespost = [NSMutableArray array];
                if ([resultone count]) {
                    NSDictionary *firstpost = resultone[0];
//                    Categories *newmogocat = [Categories new];


                    NSDictionary *thumbnail_images = [firstpost objectForKeyedSubscript:@"thumbnail_images"];
                    NSDictionary *thumbnail = [thumbnail_images objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
                    category.imageOneUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[thumbnail objectForKey:@"url"]];
//                    NSLog(@"%@", newmogocat.imageOneUrl);
//                    [imagespost addObject:newmogocat];

                    [post addObject:category];

                    [self.maincollectionView reloadData];
                }

            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
//                
//                UIAlertView *erroralert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something Wrong!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error.localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
//                [erroralert show];

            }];


        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError * responseObject) {

    }];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [post count];
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CategoryCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellidentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
//    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;


    [cell addSubview:cell.maintitleLabel];

    Categories *cat = [post objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.maincollectionView reloadInputViews];
    cell.maintitleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", cat.title];
    [cell.maintitleLabel sizeToFit];






    NSString *mainstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cat.imageOneUrl];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mainstring];
//
    [cell.mainImageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil];
//



    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The earliest you can begin to load your data is in the init method. But to be honest most of the time they get called so quickly after eachother you probably wont even notice the difference. But if you were interested, just wack it in here:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        [self loadcategoryData];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also I don't know how much data your downloading, but if you are loading a long list and it is taking a long time then maybe you should consider doing "paging" (i.e. only downloading a sub section of the data and then requesting more as the user scrolls down the page.

Comment: how can I do paging, could you please tell me how to do that. I'm new to ios @villy393

Comment: Well it depends more on your server that is supplying your results than on you. For example you load the page and then request 20 results. When the user scrolls past a certain point you then request for the next set of 20 results. So you need to figure out some means of telling your server that you want more results and what page of the results you want. Check the code for this guys infinite scroll project: https://github.com/JigarM/Infinite-UIITableview-Scroll (NB its all in Swift)

Comment: Or check out this http://jslim.net/blog/2014/04/01/infinite-scroll-using-on-uitableview/

Comment: only available for swift. anyway thanx @villy393